# Can I share codebase between OpenGL ES2- and OpenGL ES3-based renderers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

In the app I'm writing there is a class cluster that provides rendering means.  It resolves to OpenGL ES3 version when the device is capable of that, and falls back to OpenGL ES2 version otherwise. It looks roughly like the following code.

```
/* Client code */
/* `Renderer` is the class cluster instantiated like this: */
self.renderer = [Renderer rendererForAPI:self.context.API];
/* ----------- */

/* Inside `Renderer` implementation block: */
+ (instancetype)rendererForAPI:(uint)apiVersion
{
    Renderer *renderer;
    if (apiVersion >= 3) {
        renderer = [[RendererForES3 alloc] init];
    } else {
        renderer = [[RendererForES2 alloc] init];
    }

    return renderer;
}
/* --------------- */

/*
 * Both `RendererForES3` and `RendererForES2` classes
 * are descendants of `Renderer`.
 * One of them imports `OpenGLES.ES3`,
 * and the other imports `OpenGLES.ES2`.
 */
```

I do not want the code to duplicate overly. Some of my drawing methods are very similar in both members of the cluster, and some of the methods are nearly identical.
I realise that OpenGL calls, even with exactly the same name, may map to different offsets in different versions of the standard.

So the question is how to keep code duplication at its minimum.
There are two obvious solutions that sprung to my head.
The first one is to inherit ES3 Renderer from ES2 Renderer, overriding necessary methods and keeping the rest. But in that case, ES3 Renderer would receive both OpenGL imports at the same time. I'm not sure which precautions are to consider in that case, and how well will it work on different hardware.

The second solution is simply to keep the repeating code in a text file that would be included in both implementations via `#include` directive. But this seems to encumber maintenance.

Perhaps there are some advice on how to reuse code in renderers which rely on different versions of OpenGL standard. Maybe it's an architecture issue and my code should have been designed some other way.
What decision should I take?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there weren't such big differences between ES 2.0 and 3.0 as to make them incompatible (like 1.1 and 2.0), just added features and minor shader syntax differences... But I might be wrong. Haven't coded GL ES in a while, and only watched the tech notes for ES 3.0 when it came out.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I chose to subclass my ES3 renderer from the ES2 renderer.
It seems to work fine, as ES3 is emphasised as a superset of ES2.

The most noticeable drawback is that version 100 shaders and version 300 shaders can not be linked together. That means if one intends to support both ES3 and ES2, it might be necessary to have two separate shader codebases.

Also worth keeping in mind:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/AdoptingOpenGLES3/AdoptingOpenGLES3.html